# How to get current active chrome page source in c#?

Tags: c#, ui-automation, html-agility-pack

Previously, I have been using HtmlAgilityPack to get the source of current active tab in internet explorer, now I need it from Chrome maybe using Automation UI.
My previous code for IE was:

```cs
foreach (InternetExplorer nternetExplorer in (IShellWindows)instance)
{
    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nternetExplorer.FullName).ToLower().Equals("iexplore") && (nternetExplorer.LocationURL == url || nternetExplorer.LocationURL.Contains(url)))
    {
        // ISSUE: variable of a compiler-generated type
        IHTMLDocument2 document = nternetExplorer.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
        document.charset = "utf-8";
        string outerHtml = document.body.outerHTML;
    }
```

How to get current Chrome tab html page source?

Comment: Do you may be want something like `WebView2`?

Comment: I need the chrome active tab's html page source in c# as a string of html document. Then I can parse it using htmlagilitypack.